# Is whitespace at the end of a line valid CSV?

Tags: ruby, csv

If a line of a CSV file ends in whitespace (outside of the quotes) is that valid CSV?

For example:

```
require "csv"

csv1 = "\"foo\",\"bar\""
CSV.new(csv1).first
#=> ["foo", "bar"]

csv2 = "\"foo\",\"bar\" " # Note the extra space at the end of the line
CSV.new(csv2).first
#=> raises CSV::MalformedCSVError: Unclosed quoted field on line 1.
```

Does this mean the CSV is invalid? Or is this a bug in the CSV library?

Comment: At least the error message seems like a bug

Comment: @NiklasB. the error is raised when you call `first` on the CSV object (Ruby 2.1.0) so I don’t think it’s fixed.

Comment: @matt: I see, the parser seems to be lazy. Retracting my close vote. But still I think this would be a better fit for Ruby's bug tracker than for Stack Overflow

Comment: @NiklasB. I totally agree. The reason for the question is to clarify whether this is legitimate CSV. If the CSV really is malformed (space at the end of the line is invalid) then the bug is simply a confusing/inaccurate error message.

Comment: At the very least, the error message needs to be fixed

Comment: I think this is just following [RFC 4180](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180). The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) says “According to the grammar in RFC 4180, spaces outside of quotes in a field are not allowed”, which appears to be right looking at the grammar.

Comment: @matt Hmmm, maybe I misinterpreted the relevant section of the RFC. It says there is no formal definition, but then it establishes one

Comment: @NiklasB. I think the RFC is a response to the lack of formal definition – it tries to create one.

Comment: "Spaces are considered part of a field and should not be ignored." combined with "Fields containing line breaks (CRLF), double quotes, and commas should be enclosed in double-quotes." could explain that error message. Because the end double quote isn't the last character of the field, it thinks the quoting wasn't closed.

Comment: @LeviStanley Yeah there's definitely some confusion there. I retreat my comment that it is a bug in the parser

Comment: @matt Will you add an answer with those links? I think that information answers this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is just following [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180). As the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) says: “According to the grammar in RFC 4180, spaces outside of quotes in a field are not allowed”.

The relevant part of the grammar looks like:

```
record = field *(COMMA field)

field = (escaped / non-escaped)

escaped = DQUOTE *(TEXTDATA / COMMA / CR / LF / 2DQUOTE) DQUOTE
```

which doesn’t allow for whitespace outside of the quotes in a field.

This also happens with extra whitespace *within* a line, not just at the end:

```
# note extra space after the comma
csv = '"foo", "bar"'
CSV.new(csv).first
```

results in: `Illegal quoting in line 1. (CSV::MalformedCSVError)`.

Comment: I think this answer may be wrong. The critical bit is `non-escaped = *TEXTDATA` and `TEXTDATA =  %x20-21 / %x23-2B / %x2D-7E`. In ther `%x20` is the space character. This means that the sentence on Wikipedia `spaces outside of quotes in a field are not allowed` is wrong. It was introduced [in this change](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Comma-separated_values&type=revision&diff=592965137&oldid=592554922). Please ping me if my assessment is wrong.